# Getting Jenkins to use TLS / SSL with Docker

Tags: ssl, docker, https, tls, jenkins

I was looking at this wiki article:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=135468777

it says to use these options:

```
--httpPort=-1  (to stop Jenkins from listening over plain HTTP)
--httpsPort=443  (or 8443 or whatever SSL port you want Jenkins to listen on)
--httpsKeyStore="%JENKINS_HOME%\jenkins.example.com.jks"
--httpsKeyStorePassword="<cleartext-password-to-keystore>"
```

but if I have a Dockerfile that pulls from a jenkins image like so:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

then how can I add those command line arguments to the executable?

Can you do it using `CMD`?  Or would you do it like so:

```
docker run --rm jenkins --httpPort=-1  etc etc
```

it would be nice to put the arguments in `CMD` or something that goes in version control.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to Jenkins by adding `ENV JENKINS_OPTS` to your Dockerfile. For example: `ENV JENKINS_OPTS --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=443`.

Then you can put the Dockerfile to your version control.

More about this on [Jenkins Docker GitHub page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) in section "Passing Jenkins launcher parameters".